# How to list previously approved apps from "Filter Network Content" pop-ups?

Tags: macos, big-sur

It appears that when an application needs to filter or monitor network content MacOS asks the user for approval.

How can I check (either GUI or command-line) which applications have been approved before?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/webcontentfilter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
systemextensionsctl list
```

This lists all system extensions. The usage mentions a category can be given to filter the list but the manual doesn't document what categories can be provided.

Comment: As far as I can see this command does not show if a web content filter was allowed or blocked. It simply shows system extensions but those are different from web content filters. There are scenarios where somebody could have allowed the system extension but blocked the web content filter.